# Prevent Function from Running (or queue) when busy

Tags: vb.net

I have a live video stream I am trying to manipulate to determine if the image is in focus or not. To achieve this I use aforge.net with the sobel operator. The issue I am having though is that because the stream is so fast, the function I have created is not completing before it is getting called again and as such it errors up.

I start of receiving the video stream as per the below;

```
Private Sub Video_NewFrame(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal eventArgs As NewFrameEventArgs)
        Dim img As Bitmap = CType(eventArgs.Frame.Clone, Bitmap)
        'do processing here

        img_src.Image = img
        img_sobel.Image = ReturnSobel(img)
    End Sub
```

This calls my Return Sobel function which is shown below, this is used to update a PictureBox control;

```
Public Function ReturnSobel(InputImg1 As Bitmap) As Bitmap
    Dim filter1 As SobelEdgeDetector = New SobelEdgeDetector
    Dim GrayImage1 As Bitmap = Grayscale.CommonAlgorithms.BT709.Apply(InputImg1)
    filter1.ApplyInPlace(GrayImage1)
    Return GrayImage1
    filter1 = Nothing
    GrayImage1 = Nothing
End Function
```

I tried to use a queue, at the start of the program I declared q as new queue(of bitmap), then in the newframe sub added img to the queue, then in a timer I tried to pull the last frame from the queue and dequeue but although the queue kept growing (at least based on memory usage) the sobel function never appeared to be called.

I have separated it a bit, but the queue concept I had was here;

```
'at start of program
    Dim q As New Queue(Of Bitmap)

'when images are received
    q.Enqueue(img)

'part of the timer
    Dim tmpbmp As Bitmap = q.First.Clone
    img_sobel.Image = ReturnSobel(tmpbmp)
    tmpbmp = Nothing
    q.Dequeue()
```

Is there something I have done wrong with the queue concept, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Research SyncLock . I would be more helpful but I haven't finished the chapter yet, :-)

Answer (score 0):

Mary was spot in, using SyncLock was perfect. In the end I declared a new bitmap parameter (sobel) and brought the img from the newframe into that parameter, applied a synclock to that parameter and then ran the vision functions before ending the synclock.

```
> Private Sub Video_NewFrame(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal eventArgs As
> NewFrameEventArgs)
>         Dim img As Bitmap = CType(eventArgs.Frame.Clone, Bitmap)
>         Dim Sobel as Bitmap = img
>         img_src.Image = img 'do processing here
>     SyncLock Sobel
>          img_sobel.Image = ReturnSobel(Sobel)
>     End SyncLock
>     End Sub
```